# PyQt5 QTextEdit live HTML preview while editing

Tags: python, html, pyqt5, editor, qtextedit

I am trying to edit a QTextEdit named self.chatTextField to display the HTML preview in a live format. For example if I do "" I want it to not show the tag, but bold the text. I am able to have this work if I use textBrowswer as a previewer, but I would like it all to be in one widget.

[image]

As you can see in the image above, I want match the part the displays the HTML as final product and not the tags. Is this possible?

I have tried various ways to convert .toPlainText() and then adding an HTML header and footer. I have tried to .insertHtml() and .setHtml(). I have tried to do tricks with open and close carrots, but nothing seems to be working. I am either getting it to simply remove all HTML (anything with carrots/tags) or it is causing recursion errors.

This is the only section of code that is dealing with updating the HTML. If you need further code please let me know. I can provide UI file as well.

```
def printMaster(self):
    global my_text

    if self.chatTextField.toPlainText() != "":
        oldText = self.chatTextField.toPlainText()
        newText = self.textBrowser.toPlainText()
        if oldText != newText and oldText != my_text:
            self.textBrowser.setText(self.chatTextField.toPlainText())
            my_text = self.chatTextField.toPlainText()
            if my_text.endswith('>'):
                #my_text = self.chatTextField.toHtml()

                # self.chatTextField.clear()
                print(my_text)
                # self.chatTextField.setHtml(my_text)
                QCoreApplication.processEvents()



            # cursor = self.chatTextField.textCursor()
            # pos = cursor.selectionEnd()
            #
            # print(self.chatTextField.toHtml())
            #
            # my_text = self.chatTextField.toHtml()
            #
            # self.chatTextField.clear()
            # # self.chatTextField.insertHtml(str(my_text))
            #
            # if my_text.endswith('<'):
            #     my_text = my_text + "<"
            #     self.chatTextField.setHtml(my_text)
            #     print(True)
            # else:
            #     self.chatTextField.insertHtml(my_text)
            #
            #
            # cursor.setPosition(pos)
            #
            # self.chatTextField.setTextCursor(cursor)
            #
            #
            # QCoreApplication.processEvents()
            #
            # # self.chatTextField.show()
```

Comment: I did not understand your question, could you explain me better

Comment: Of course I can try. So you see in the 2nd object where the text is bold and also red? I want my input object the (the bottom box that has the <b> and other HTML tags in it) to look like the 2nd object. Instead of SHOWING <b> I just want the text to be bold for example. Does that make more sense?

Comment: That is, you want that there is only one view, and if that view is typed `<b>Bold</b>` in the same view it should show the word "Bold" in bold, am I right?

Comment: Correct that is what I want. Is that possible?